# How to copy a file line by line keeping its original line breaks

Tags: java, file-io, copy, newline

I need to replace keys in various files (all types and line break format). 
To do this, i tried to copy the file line by line and replace keys in the line. This works but original line breaks are lost.

Here is my code, quite common:

```
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fis));

FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(tmpFile);
BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(writer);

String line;
while ((line = reader.readLine() != null) {
    String updatedLine = replaceKeys(line);
    out.write(updatedLine);
    out.newLine();
}
```

I need to read the file line by line to be able to replace keys correctly (keys are determined by some delimiters, they must not be cut during file reading).

The problem is my unix files (.sh) has wrong line breaks after replacement (code is run on windows). And files with only one line is changed into a 2-lines file.

Question is, how to keep original file line breaks while copying the file line by line or, at least, how to be able to determine the end of the file to not add an additional line at the end? Thanks for your help.

*Edit: Useless DataInputStream removed.*

Comment: What’s the purpose of the `DataInputStream`? Why don’t you pass the `FileInputStream` to the `InputStreamReader` directly?

Comment: Well seen, thanks for the tip. This is a bad copy paste. It works well without DataInputStream.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a [`Scanner`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) for this job:

```
try(Scanner s=new Scanner(file).useDelimiter("(?<=\n)|(?!\n)(?<=\r)");
    FileWriter out=new FileWriter(tmpFile)) {

    while(s.hasNext()){
        String line=s.next();
        String updatedLine = replaceKeys(line);
        out.write(updatedLine);
    }
}
```

The key point is the [*regex*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#sum) specified as delimiter. The pattern used above will match what [`BufferedReader.readLine()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine--) matches for a line break, that is, a `'\n'`, `'\r'` followed by `'\n'`, or a lone `'\r'`. But it uses “zero width lookbehind” to match the *position* after the line break rather than the line break itself so the line break becomes part of the token returned by `Scanner.next()`.

So the `String line` will contain the line break at its end, unless it’s the last line not terminated by a line break. So all you have to do, assuming that `replaceKeys` leaves the line break untouched, is to write the `String`as-is without appending a line break manually.

If `replaceKeys` can not cope with the `String` having a line break at its end, you have to split it before calling the method and joining afterwards.

Comment: It works like a charm! I was blocked on this one. As i can't find a good way on google, this may help other person too. Thank you so much for you help.